# SAPJCO3 libraries in Mule domain

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, sapjco3

I'm going to develop couple of Mule applications that will use SAP connector so I'd like to keep SAP libraries (sapjco3.jar, sapidoc3.jar and native sapjco3.dll) in the Mule domain however I'm struggling with how to export sapjco3.dll.

I'm not using MVN and I tried to place **sapjco3.dll** to the project **/lib** folder, also to src/main/domain/lib and src/main/resources/lib folder ... but it seems that Mule Eclipse plugin always ignores it when **exporting the domain as "Anypoint Studio Project to Mule Deployable Archive"**.

Are there any best practises how to organise this in the domain ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to organize these in the project when your exporting from Studio. But instead of keeping these jar files as part of the project, you can keep in the mule standalone server in the below locations

--> $MULE_HOME/lib/user

--> $MULE_HOME/lib/native

for further details, refer the mule documentation 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mulesoft-enterprise-java-connector-for-sap-reference